# Mysql slow.log user specific

Tags: mysql, performance, users, configuration, slow-log

I use a slow.log logging on my MySQL server, to catch bottlenecks in my script, but at the same time, i use phpmyadmin on this server. My script and pma has different MySQL user accounts and now, when i analyzing the slow.log file, i see a lot of spam from pma queries, is it possible, to configure the MySQL to logging a slow queries only from specific users?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running ???

Answer (score 2):

You can try to analyse your slow log with the Percona tool **[pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html)** and use the option :

```
–filter ‘($event->{user} || “”) =~ m/john/’
```

Max.